# SQL : How to create a table with auto-computed column values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

**Problem** : Trying to create a column named 'duration' that auto-inserts its value based on the difference of the columns 'start_time' and 'end_time'.

**SQL Dialect** : PostgreSQL

**Here's what I've tried**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_example (
    start_time BIGINT,
    end_time BIGINT,
    duration BIGINT AS DIFFERENCE(start_time, end_time)
)
```

**Question** : Using SQL DDL How do you auto-compute the value of the difference of two other columns as its value in an SQL 'CREATE TABLE' statement?

**Goal** : Example of what table should look like on SQL insert statement

`insert into my_table_example (1, 2)`

`insert into my_table_example (2, 5)`

`insert into my_table_example (1, 7)`

```
my_table_example
+------------+-----------+----------+
| start_Time | end_time  | duration |
+------------+-----------+----------+
|     1      |     2     |    1     |
|     2      |     5     |    3     |
|     1      |     7     |    6     | 
+------------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have tried the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html)...

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_example (
    start_time timestamp,
    end_time timestamp,
    duration interval GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( end_time - start_time ) STORED
);

INSERT INTO my_table_example(start_time, end_time) 
VALUES ('2023-10-01 23:00', '2023-10-02 14:00') 
RETURNING *;
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. I guess the 'stored' indicates that the table should insert this value?

Comment: The manual is free to use, even to copy some content: `The keyword STORED must be specified to choose the stored kind of generated column. See CREATE TABLE for more details.`

Comment: @FrankHeikens - a bit disingenuous as there's no other kind of `GENERATED` column! :-)